# Unit test for helper which changes behavior based on current path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to test the following helper method in rails:

```
  def current_has_class_link(text, path, class_name="selected")
    link_to_unless_current(text, path) do
      link_to(text, path, :class => class_name)
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to make a test which is something like this:

```
  describe "current_has_class_link" do
    let(:link_path){ listings_path }
    let(:link_text){ "Listings" }

    it "should render a normal link if not on current path" do
      html = "<a href=\"#{link_path}\">#{link_text}</a>"
      current_has_class_link(link_text, link_path).should == html
    end

    it "should add a class if on the links path" do
      # at this point I need to force current_path to return the same as link_path
      html = "<a href=\"#{link_path}\" class=\"selected\">#{link_text}</a>"
      current_has_class_link(link_text, link_path).should == html
    end
  end
```

Now obviously I could use an integration test for this but that seems like overkil to me. Is there a way that I can stub `current_page?` so that it returns what I need?

I tried to do

```
ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.stub(current_page?({controller: 'listings', action: 'index'})).and_return(link_path)
```

But that gives me an error which I don't really understand:

```
Failures:

  1) ApplicationHelper current_has_class_link should add a class if on the links path
     Failure/Error: ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper.stub(current_page?({controller: 'listings', action: 'index'})).and_return(link_path)
     RuntimeError:
       You cannot use helpers that need to determine the current page unless your view context provides a Request object in a #request method
     # ./spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue and stubbed it at the test level instead.

```
self.stub!("current_page?").and_return(true)
```

Comment: This is now deprecated syntax, so using the new RSpec syntax you can do:
`expect(self).to receive(:current_page?).and_return(false)`

Answer (score 3):

Within `Test:Unit` you can use an `attr_reader` to set the request as a method.

```
class ActiveLinkHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  attr_reader :request

  test "should render a normal link if not on current path" do
    html = "<a href=\"#{link_path}\">#{link_text}</a>"
    assert_equal html, current_has_class_link(link_text, link_path)
  end

  test "should add a class if on the links path" do
    # Path can be set.
    #   note: the default is an empty string that will never match)
    request.path = link_path

    html = "<a href=\"#{link_path}\" class=\"selected\">#{link_text}</a>"
    assert_equal html, current_has_class_link(link_text, link_path)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
view.stub!(:current_page?).and_return(true)
```